# ImportError: cannot import name 'chatbot' from 'chatterbot'

Tags: python, chatbot, python-3.7, chatterbot

hey guys I'm getting this error, trying to build a chatbot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Edwrd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\FRIDAY.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot import Chatbot
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chatbot' from 'chatterbot' (C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `from chatterbot import ChatBot`

Instead of `from chatterbot import Chatbot` like you have it

Just a heads up: *generally* with import errors like this, it's a spelling issue :)

Comment: changed it but still got he same issue --------    ImportError: cannot import name 'Chatbot' from 'chatterbot' (C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py)

Comment: No you didn't. Notice the spelling of `ChatBot`, you used `Chatbot` again.

Comment: @Edward: The error message in your comment says it can't import `Chatbot` **not** `ChatBot` as suggested in this answer _and_ shown in the [documentation](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#create-a-new-chat-bot).

Answer (score 1):

For `chatterbot-1.0.5` I had to do the following:

```
from chatterbot.chatterbot import ChatBot
```

Comment: The docs don't indicate this is the correct way to import it, so I don't know if something has changed recently.

Comment: ok, got it! FishMonkeys suggestion worked for me. thanks for your help as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
Capitalize the C and B made solved this error issue:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
```